# peers went offline in fabric2.3

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, grpc

I build a 50 peers in org1 an 1 peer in org2 following test-network(fabric version 2.3.2). after all the peers join the channel, the peer started gossiping.

`2021-11-30 13:05:21.882 UTC [gossip.channel] reportMembershipChanges -> INFO 04f [[mychannel] Membership view has changed. peers went online:  [[peer16.org1.example.com:6032] [peer29.org1.example.com:6058] [peer27.org1.example.com:6054] [peer21.org1.example.com:6042] [peer9.org1.example.com:6018] [peer1.org1.example.com:6002]] , current view:  [[peer7.org1.example.com:6014] [peer37.org1.example.com:6074] [peer16.org1.example.com:6032] [peer29.org1.example.com:6058] [peer0.org1.example.com:7051] [peer17.org1.example.com:6034] [peer27.org1.example.com:6054] [peer21.org1.example.com:6042] [peer0.org2.example.com:9051 ] [peer9.org1.example.com:6018] [peer1.org1.example.com:6002]]]`

But about 4 seconds like peer29.org1.example.com, it went offline. Other peers also went offline like it. Finally, all the connection between the peers and also order node got closed.

```
2021-11-30 13:05:25.771 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 06d Entering [681f328f15a0aab216ad94f340a1fb06fe315d70a122064955a2191e3442e3c5]
2021-11-30 13:05:25.771 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 06e Closing connection to Endpoint: peer29.org1.example.com:6058, InternalEndpoint: peer29.org1.example.com:6058, PKI-ID: 681f328f15a0aab216ad94f340a1fb06fe315d70a122064955a2191e3442e3c5, Metadata: 
2021-11-30 13:05:25.771 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 06f Exiting
```

I want to know what's worng with my fabric network. Do I need to modify some parameters in core.yaml or other configuration file？
full logs under:

```
 Version: 2.3.2
 Commit SHA: 0022e8f
 Go version: go1.15.7
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
 Chaincode:
  Base Docker Label: org.hyperledger.fabric
  Docker Namespace: hyperledger
2021-11-30 13:01:33.210 UTC [peer] getLocalAddress -> INFO 002 Auto-detected peer address: 172.26.0.25:6046
2021-11-30 13:01:33.210 UTC [peer] getLocalAddress -> INFO 003 Returning peer23.org1.example.com:6046
2021-11-30 13:01:33.212 UTC [nodeCmd] initGrpcSemaphores -> INFO 004 concurrency limit for endorser service is 2500
2021-11-30 13:01:33.212 UTC [nodeCmd] initGrpcSemaphores -> INFO 005 concurrency limit for deliver service is 2500
2021-11-30 13:01:33.212 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 006 Starting peer with TLS enabled
2021-11-30 13:01:33.221 UTC [certmonitor] trackCertExpiration -> INFO 007 The enrollment certificate will expire on 2031-11-28 12:56:00 +0000 UTC
2021-11-30 13:01:33.222 UTC [certmonitor] trackCertExpiration -> INFO 008 The server TLS certificate will expire on 2031-11-28 12:56:00 +0000 UTC
2021-11-30 13:01:33.222 UTC [ledgermgmt] NewLedgerMgr -> INFO 009 Initializing LedgerMgr
2021-11-30 13:01:33.239 UTC [leveldbhelper] openDBAndCheckFormat -> INFO 00a DB is empty Setting db format as 2.0
2021-11-30 13:01:33.240 UTC [blkstorage] NewProvider -> INFO 00b Creating new file ledger directory at /var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains/chains
2021-11-30 13:01:33.251 UTC [leveldbhelper] openDBAndCheckFormat -> INFO 00c DB is empty Setting db format as 2.0
2021-11-30 13:01:33.268 UTC [leveldbhelper] openDBAndCheckFormat -> INFO 00d DB is empty Setting db format as 2.0
2021-11-30 13:01:33.270 UTC [ledgermgmt] NewLedgerMgr -> INFO 00e Initialized LedgerMgr
2021-11-30 13:01:33.271 UTC [gossip.service] New -> INFO 00f Initialize gossip with endpoint peer23.org1.example.com:6046
2021-11-30 13:01:33.272 UTC [gossip.gossip] New -> INFO 010 Creating gossip service with self membership of Endpoint: peer23.org1.example.com:6046, InternalEndpoint: peer23.org1.example.com:6046, PKI-ID: f71ef56807b59b1b8f563adc2d9d2546e06a24401c1e73a3f306ae53099c42d8, Metadata: 
2021-11-30 13:01:33.272 UTC [lifecycle] InitializeLocalChaincodes -> INFO 011 Initialized lifecycle cache with 0 already installed chaincodes
2021-11-30 13:01:33.272 UTC [gossip.gossip] start -> INFO 012 Gossip instance peer23.org1.example.com:6046 started
2021-11-30 13:01:33.273 UTC [nodeCmd] computeChaincodeEndpoint -> INFO 013 Entering computeChaincodeEndpoint with peerHostname: peer23.org1.example.com
2021-11-30 13:01:33.273 UTC [nodeCmd] computeChaincodeEndpoint -> INFO 014 Exit with ccEndpoint: peer23.org1.example.com:6047
2021-11-30 13:01:33.274 UTC [sccapi] DeploySysCC -> INFO 015 deploying system chaincode 'lscc'
2021-11-30 13:01:33.274 UTC [sccapi] DeploySysCC -> INFO 016 deploying system chaincode 'cscc'
2021-11-30 13:01:33.274 UTC [sccapi] DeploySysCC -> INFO 017 deploying system chaincode 'qscc'
2021-11-30 13:01:33.274 UTC [sccapi] DeploySysCC -> INFO 018 deploying system chaincode '_lifecycle'
2021-11-30 13:01:33.274 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 019 Deployed system chaincodes
2021-11-30 13:01:33.274 UTC [discovery] NewService -> INFO 01a Created with config TLS: true, authCacheMaxSize: 1000, authCachePurgeRatio: 0.750000
2021-11-30 13:01:33.274 UTC [nodeCmd] registerDiscoveryService -> INFO 01b Discovery service activated
2021-11-30 13:01:33.274 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 01c Starting peer with ID=[peer23.org1.example.com], network ID=[dev], address=[peer23.org1.example.com:6046]
2021-11-30 13:01:33.275 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 01d Started peer with ID=[peer23.org1.example.com], network ID=[dev], address=[peer23.org1.example.com:6046]
2021-11-30 13:01:33.275 UTC [kvledger] LoadPreResetHeight -> INFO 01e Loading prereset height from path [/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains]
2021-11-30 13:01:33.275 UTC [blkstorage] preResetHtFiles -> INFO 01f No active channels passed
2021-11-30 13:03:36.865 UTC [ledgermgmt] CreateLedger -> INFO 020 Creating ledger [mychannel] with genesis block
2021-11-30 13:03:36.867 UTC [blkstorage] newBlockfileMgr -> INFO 021 Getting block information from block storage
2021-11-30 13:03:36.877 UTC [kvledger] commit -> INFO 022 [mychannel] Committed block [0] with 1 transaction(s) in 6ms (state_validation=0ms block_and_pvtdata_commit=3ms state_commit=1ms) commitHash=[]
2021-11-30 13:03:36.877 UTC [kvledger] updateLedgerStatus -> INFO 023 Updating ledger [mychannel] status to [ACTIVE]
2021-11-30 13:03:36.878 UTC [ledgermgmt] CreateLedger -> INFO 024 Created ledger [mychannel] with genesis block
2021-11-30 13:03:36.881 UTC [peer.orderers] Update -> WARN 025 Config defines both orderer org specific endpoints and global endpoints, global endpoints will be ignored channel=mychannel
2021-11-30 13:03:36.881 UTC [gossip.gossip] JoinChan -> INFO 026 Joining gossip network of channel mychannel with 2 organizations
2021-11-30 13:03:36.881 UTC [gossip.gossip] learnAnchorPeers -> INFO 027 No configured anchor peers of Org1MSP for channel mychannel to learn about
2021-11-30 13:03:36.881 UTC [gossip.gossip] learnAnchorPeers -> INFO 028 No configured anchor peers of Org2MSP for channel mychannel to learn about
2021-11-30 13:03:36.882 UTC [gossip.state] NewGossipStateProvider -> INFO 029 Updating metadata information for channel mychannel, current ledger sequence is at = 0, next expected block is = 1
2021-11-30 13:03:36.882 UTC [deliveryClient] StartDeliverForChannel -> INFO 02a This peer will retrieve blocks from ordering service and disseminate to other peers in the organization for channel mychannel
2021-11-30 13:03:36.882 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 02b finished chaincode: cscc duration: 19ms channel= txID=8835eaa5
2021-11-30 13:03:36.882 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 02c unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.26.0.1:32942 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=20.909906ms
2021-11-30 13:05:01.965 UTC [gossip.privdata] StoreBlock -> INFO 02d Received block [1] from buffer channel=mychannel
2021-11-30 13:05:01.969 UTC [peer.orderers] Update -> WARN 02e Config defines both orderer org specific endpoints and global endpoints, global endpoints will be ignored channel=mychannel
2021-11-30 13:05:01.969 UTC [gossip.gossip] JoinChan -> INFO 02f Joining gossip network of channel mychannel with 2 organizations
2021-11-30 13:05:01.969 UTC [gossip.gossip] learnAnchorPeers -> INFO 030 No configured anchor peers of Org2MSP for channel mychannel to learn about
2021-11-30 13:05:01.969 UTC [gossip.gossip] learnAnchorPeers -> INFO 031 Learning about the configured anchor peers of Org1MSP for channel mychannel: [{peer0.org1.example.com 7051}]
2021-11-30 13:05:01.969 UTC [committer.txvalidator] Validate -> INFO 032 [mychannel] Validated block [1] in 3ms
2021-11-30 13:05:02.023 UTC [kvledger] commit -> INFO 033 [mychannel] Committed block [1] with 1 transaction(s) in 53ms (state_validation=0ms block_and_pvtdata_commit=34ms state_commit=3ms) commitHash=[47dc540c94ceb704a23875c11273e16bb0b8a87aed84de911f2133568115f254]
2021-11-30 13:05:02.545 UTC [gossip.privdata] StoreBlock -> INFO 034 Received block [2] from buffer channel=mychannel
2021-11-30 13:05:02.557 UTC [peer.orderers] Update -> WARN 035 Config defines both orderer org specific endpoints and global endpoints, global endpoints will be ignored channel=mychannel
2021-11-30 13:05:02.558 UTC [gossip.gossip] JoinChan -> INFO 036 Joining gossip network of channel mychannel with 2 organizations
2021-11-30 13:05:02.558 UTC [gossip.gossip] learnAnchorPeers -> INFO 037 Learning about the configured anchor peers of Org1MSP for channel mychannel: [{peer0.org1.example.com 7051}]
2021-11-30 13:05:02.558 UTC [gossip.gossip] learnAnchorPeers -> INFO 038 Learning about the configured anchor peers of Org2MSP for channel mychannel: [{peer0.org2.example.com 9051}]
2021-11-30 13:05:02.559 UTC [committer.txvalidator] Validate -> INFO 039 [mychannel] Validated block [2] in 8ms
2021-11-30 13:05:02.575 UTC [kvledger] commit -> INFO 03a [mychannel] Committed block [2] with 1 transaction(s) in 13ms (state_validation=0ms block_and_pvtdata_commit=11ms state_commit=0ms) commitHash=[5f88b61407b149a48413433f4670c46531e5c4a8febdc339a9536ff8716a559e]
2021-11-30 13:05:04.002 UTC [gossip.gossip] validateMsg -> WARN 03b StateInfo message GossipMessage: Channel: , nonce: 0, tag: CHAN_OR_ORG state_info_message: Timestamp:inc_num:1638277419992095507 seq_num:1638277502624567318 PKI-id:7c354a15dd1f64906b18b99434df64e3c6944daf2244eb06b2f18a3e8a35a667 channel MAC:22055448f06965c89a7279c19d81c428fac2c2a78aa3376696d375c036786496 properties:ledger_height:3 chaincodes:<name:"_lifecycle" version:"1" > , Envelope: 115 bytes, Signature: 71 bytes is found invalid: PKIID wasn't found
2021-11-30 13:05:04.002 UTC [gossip.gossip] handleMessage -> WARN 03c Message GossipMessage: Channel: , nonce: 0, tag: CHAN_OR_ORG state_info_message: Timestamp:inc_num:1638277419992095507 seq_num:1638277502624567318 PKI-id:7c354a15dd1f64906b18b99434df64e3c6944daf2244eb06b2f18a3e8a35a667 channel MAC:22055448f06965c89a7279c19d81c428fac2c2a78aa3376696d375c036786496 properties:ledger_height:3 chaincodes:<name:"_lifecycle" version:"1" > , Envelope: 115 bytes, Signature: 71 bytes isn't valid
2021-11-30 13:05:04.303 UTC [gossip.gossip] validateMsg -> WARN 03d StateInfo message GossipMessage: Channel: , nonce: 0, tag: CHAN_OR_ORG state_info_message: Timestamp:inc_num:1638277360287457345 seq_num:1638277502566418919 PKI-id:c8b9f4e5cc858020476a3ff082fa42f35234d461cf332e571458419580401a66 channel MAC:88de315faa949f137a852afcae0e79d57eeecdc12fb3fa752c16bf4ec2c0caff properties:ledger_height:3 chaincodes:<name:"_lifecycle" version:"1" > , Envelope: 115 bytes, Signature: 70 bytes is found invalid: PKIID wasn't found
2021-11-30 13:05:04.303 UTC [gossip.gossip] handleMessage -> WARN 03e Message GossipMessage: Channel: , nonce: 0, tag: CHAN_OR_ORG state_info_message: Timestamp:inc_num:1638277360287457345 seq_num:1638277502566418919 PKI-id:c8b9f4e5cc858020476a3ff082fa42f35234d461cf332e571458419580401a66 channel MAC:88de315faa949f137a852afcae0e79d57eeecdc12fb3fa752c16bf4ec2c0caff properties:ledger_height:3 chaincodes:<name:"_lifecycle" version:"1" > , Envelope: 115 bytes, Signature: 70 bytes isn't valid
2021-11-30 13:05:05.952 UTC [gossip.gossip] validateMsg -> WARN 03f StateInfo message GossipMessage: Channel: , nonce: 0, tag: CHAN_OR_ORG state_info_message: Timestamp:inc_num:1638277441935760487 seq_num:1638277502594605583 PKI-id:a7893ec6f65343b9eaf054afff299065fe84400e5dc49c7258ea60a637536503 channel MAC:e712c996f30524d483a6892342087f6f12bfe3fb534f2649e2fc253ce36f0f02 properties:ledger_height:3 chaincodes:<name:"_lifecycle" version:"1" > , Envelope: 115 bytes, Signature: 70 bytes is found invalid: PKIID wasn't found
2021-11-30 13:05:05.952 UTC [gossip.gossip] handleMessage -> WARN 040 Message GossipMessage: Channel: , nonce: 0, tag: CHAN_OR_ORG state_info_message: Timestamp:inc_num:1638277441935760487 seq_num:1638277502594605583 PKI-id:a7893ec6f65343b9eaf054afff299065fe84400e5dc49c7258ea60a637536503 channel MAC:e712c996f30524d483a6892342087f6f12bfe3fb534f2649e2fc253ce36f0f02 properties:ledger_height:3 chaincodes:<name:"_lifecycle" version:"1" > , Envelope: 115 bytes, Signature: 70 bytes isn't valid
2021-11-30 13:05:06.036 UTC [gossip.gossip] validateMsg -> WARN 041 StateInfo message GossipMessage: Channel: , nonce: 0, tag: CHAN_OR_ORG state_info_message: Timestamp:inc_num:1638277354017175583 seq_num:1638277502565280187 PKI-id:6b676ead59f83459bc19c3d77776bc3e69dd7eb3464545131eb0a3f4e221eb6a channel MAC:ec4860cc14970722150113c251f48061bed9690b29776e466dc4298aca6b8f64 properties:ledger_height:3 chaincodes:<name:"_lifecycle" version:"1" > , Envelope: 115 bytes, Signature: 71 bytes is found invalid: PKIID wasn't found
2021-11-30 13:05:06.036 UTC [gossip.gossip] handleMessage -> WARN 042 Message GossipMessage: Channel: , nonce: 0, tag: CHAN_OR_ORG state_info_message: Timestamp:inc_num:1638277354017175583 seq_num:1638277502565280187 PKI-id:6b676ead59f83459bc19c3d77776bc3e69dd7eb3464545131eb0a3f4e221eb6a channel MAC:ec4860cc14970722150113c251f48061bed9690b29776e466dc4298aca6b8f64 properties:ledger_height:3 chaincodes:<name:"_lifecycle" version:"1" > , Envelope: 115 bytes, Signature: 71 bytes isn't valid
2021-11-30 13:05:06.237 UTC [gossip.gossip] validateMsg -> WARN 043 StateInfo message GossipMessage: Channel: , nonce: 0, tag: CHAN_OR_ORG state_info_message: Timestamp:inc_num:1638277498216754322 seq_num:1638277502572743453 PKI-id:602e9c41afef280cf2122c1431b1436a23269fdac7606c2337f2d4f328248a81 channel MAC:80ec838cbd4b26e20f903d66a6a8f5cfc669d44ec13963b63cfd07b6583b5840 properties:ledger_height:3 chaincodes:<name:"_lifecycle" version:"1" > , Envelope: 115 bytes, Signature: 70 bytes is found invalid: PKIID wasn't found
2021-11-30 13:05:06.237 UTC [gossip.gossip] handleMessage -> WARN 044 Message GossipMessage: Channel: , nonce: 0, tag: CHAN_OR_ORG state_info_message: Timestamp:inc_num:1638277498216754322 seq_num:1638277502572743453 PKI-id:602e9c41afef280cf2122c1431b1436a23269fdac7606c2337f2d4f328248a81 channel MAC:80ec838cbd4b26e20f903d66a6a8f5cfc669d44ec13963b63cfd07b6583b5840 properties:ledger_height:3 chaincodes:<name:"_lifecycle" version:"1" > , Envelope: 115 bytes, Signature: 70 bytes isn't valid
2021-11-30 13:05:06.881 UTC [gossip.channel] reportMembershipChanges -> INFO 045 [[mychannel] Membership view has changed. peers went online:  [[peer0.org2.example.com:9051 ]] , current view:  [[peer0.org2.example.com:9051 ]]]
2021-11-30 13:05:16.881 UTC [gossip.channel] reportMembershipChanges -> INFO 046 [[mychannel] Membership view has changed. peers went online:  [[peer37.org1.example.com:6074] [peer0.org1.example.com:7051] [peer17.org1.example.com:6034] [peer7.org1.example.com:6014]] , current view:  [[peer0.org2.example.com:9051 ] [peer37.org1.example.com:6074] [peer0.org1.example.com:7051] [peer17.org1.example.com:6034] [peer7.org1.example.com:6014]]]
2021-11-30 13:05:21.300 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN 047 Failed obtaining connection for peer15.org1.example.com:6030, PKIid:e55a5ed02b8abe80dca04c8d228a0b263ffc95450804c2efa2c29ee0060218ea reason: context deadline exceeded
2021-11-30 13:05:21.301 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 048 Entering [e55a5ed02b8abe80dca04c8d228a0b263ffc95450804c2efa2c29ee0060218ea]
2021-11-30 13:05:21.301 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 049 Closing connection to Endpoint: peer15.org1.example.com:6030, InternalEndpoint: , PKI-ID: e55a5ed02b8abe80dca04c8d228a0b263ffc95450804c2efa2c29ee0060218ea, Metadata: 
2021-11-30 13:05:21.301 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 04a Exiting
2021-11-30 13:05:21.414 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN 04b Failed obtaining connection for peer46.org1.example.com:6092, PKIid:b3155b80ee8349a302c8c3cf54f42d5033ca321de54d0e260c28c64c7f83ed5f reason: context deadline exceeded
2021-11-30 13:05:21.414 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 04c Entering [b3155b80ee8349a302c8c3cf54f42d5033ca321de54d0e260c28c64c7f83ed5f]
2021-11-30 13:05:21.414 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 04d Closing connection to Endpoint: peer46.org1.example.com:6092, InternalEndpoint: peer46.org1.example.com:6092, PKI-ID: b3155b80ee8349a302c8c3cf54f42d5033ca321de54d0e260c28c64c7f83ed5f, Metadata: 
2021-11-30 13:05:21.414 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 04e Exiting
2021-11-30 13:05:21.882 UTC [gossip.channel] reportMembershipChanges -> INFO 04f [[mychannel] Membership view has changed. peers went online:  [[peer16.org1.example.com:6032] [peer29.org1.example.com:6058] [peer27.org1.example.com:6054] [peer21.org1.example.com:6042] [peer9.org1.example.com:6018] [peer1.org1.example.com:6002]] , current view:  [[peer7.org1.example.com:6014] [peer37.org1.example.com:6074] [peer16.org1.example.com:6032] [peer29.org1.example.com:6058] [peer0.org1.example.com:7051] [peer17.org1.example.com:6034] [peer27.org1.example.com:6054] [peer21.org1.example.com:6042] [peer0.org2.example.com:9051 ] [peer9.org1.example.com:6018] [peer1.org1.example.com:6002]]]
2021-11-30 13:05:22.823 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN 050 Failed obtaining connection for peer1.org1.example.com:6002, PKIid:d7995c909c6cf8430beae66c2936e6d73ae5c6078aaad55a52e357233aaa4407 reason: context deadline exceeded
2021-11-30 13:05:22.823 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 051 Entering [d7995c909c6cf8430beae66c2936e6d73ae5c6078aaad55a52e357233aaa4407]
2021-11-30 13:05:22.823 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 052 Closing connection to Endpoint: peer1.org1.example.com:6002, InternalEndpoint: peer1.org1.example.com:6002, PKI-ID: d7995c909c6cf8430beae66c2936e6d73ae5c6078aaad55a52e357233aaa4407, Metadata: 
2021-11-30 13:05:22.823 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 053 Exiting
2021-11-30 13:05:24.301 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN 055 Failed obtaining connection for peer49.org1.example.com:6098, PKIid:602e9c41afef280cf2122c1431b1436a23269fdac7606c2337f2d4f328248a81 reason: context deadline exceeded
2021-11-30 13:05:24.301 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN 056 Failed obtaining connection for peer36.org1.example.com:6072, PKIid:0a4db96929e5c8a148d594fe59de0fa71ab59f8fe258ebefa50613718f8f2fbf reason: context deadline exceeded
2021-11-30 13:05:24.301 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 057 Entering [602e9c41afef280cf2122c1431b1436a23269fdac7606c2337f2d4f328248a81]
2021-11-30 13:05:24.301 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN 054 Failed obtaining connection for peer15.org1.example.com:6030, PKIid:e55a5ed02b8abe80dca04c8d228a0b263ffc95450804c2efa2c29ee0060218ea reason: context deadline exceeded
2021-11-30 13:05:24.302 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 058 Closing connection to Endpoint: peer49.org1.example.com:6098, InternalEndpoint: peer49.org1.example.com:6098, PKI-ID: 602e9c41afef280cf2122c1431b1436a23269fdac7606c2337f2d4f328248a81, Metadata: 
2021-11-30 13:05:24.302 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 059 Exiting
2021-11-30 13:05:24.302 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 05a Entering [0a4db96929e5c8a148d594fe59de0fa71ab59f8fe258ebefa50613718f8f2fbf]
2021-11-30 13:05:24.302 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 05b Closing connection to Endpoint: peer36.org1.example.com:6072, InternalEndpoint: peer36.org1.example.com:6072, PKI-ID: 0a4db96929e5c8a148d594fe59de0fa71ab59f8fe258ebefa50613718f8f2fbf, Metadata: 
2021-11-30 13:05:24.302 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 05c Exiting
2021-11-30 13:05:24.302 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 05d Entering [e55a5ed02b8abe80dca04c8d228a0b263ffc95450804c2efa2c29ee0060218ea]
2021-11-30 13:05:24.302 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 05e Closing connection to Endpoint: peer15.org1.example.com:6030, InternalEndpoint: , PKI-ID: e55a5ed02b8abe80dca04c8d228a0b263ffc95450804c2efa2c29ee0060218ea, Metadata: 
2021-11-30 13:05:24.302 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 05f Exiting
2021-11-30 13:05:24.415 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN 060 Failed obtaining connection for peer46.org1.example.com:6092, PKIid:b3155b80ee8349a302c8c3cf54f42d5033ca321de54d0e260c28c64c7f83ed5f reason: context deadline exceeded
2021-11-30 13:05:24.415 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 061 Entering [b3155b80ee8349a302c8c3cf54f42d5033ca321de54d0e260c28c64c7f83ed5f]
2021-11-30 13:05:24.415 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 062 Closing connection to Endpoint: peer46.org1.example.com:6092, InternalEndpoint: peer46.org1.example.com:6092, PKI-ID: b3155b80ee8349a302c8c3cf54f42d5033ca321de54d0e260c28c64c7f83ed5f, Metadata: 
2021-11-30 13:05:24.415 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 063 Exiting
2021-11-30 13:05:25.624 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN 064 Failed obtaining connection for peer10.org1.example.com:6020, PKIid:1d7304f21bb017736e411da90b9a9830847473d193a09e6fffb8051df2ef0fb7 reason: context deadline exceeded
2021-11-30 13:05:25.624 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 065 Entering [1d7304f21bb017736e411da90b9a9830847473d193a09e6fffb8051df2ef0fb7]
2021-11-30 13:05:25.624 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 066 Closing connection to Endpoint: peer10.org1.example.com:6020, InternalEndpoint: peer10.org1.example.com:6020, PKI-ID: 1d7304f21bb017736e411da90b9a9830847473d193a09e6fffb8051df2ef0fb7, Metadata: 
2021-11-30 13:05:25.625 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 067 Exiting
2021-11-30 13:05:25.656 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN 068 Failed obtaining connection for peer41.org1.example.com:6082, PKIid:45501f3933ebf6e3e553396caf5ca5a76277c36a38eb66c2f61d250c8a524c94 reason: context deadline exceeded
2021-11-30 13:05:25.656 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 069 Entering [45501f3933ebf6e3e553396caf5ca5a76277c36a38eb66c2f61d250c8a524c94]
2021-11-30 13:05:25.656 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 06a Closing connection to Endpoint: peer41.org1.example.com:6082, InternalEndpoint: peer41.org1.example.com:6082, PKI-ID: 45501f3933ebf6e3e553396caf5ca5a76277c36a38eb66c2f61d250c8a524c94, Metadata: 
2021-11-30 13:05:25.656 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 06b Exiting
2021-11-30 13:05:25.770 UTC [gossip.comm] sendToEndpoint -> WARN 06c Failed obtaining connection for peer29.org1.example.com:6058, PKIid:681f328f15a0aab216ad94f340a1fb06fe315d70a122064955a2191e3442e3c5 reason: context deadline exceeded
2021-11-30 13:05:25.771 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 06d Entering [681f328f15a0aab216ad94f340a1fb06fe315d70a122064955a2191e3442e3c5]
2021-11-30 13:05:25.771 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 06e Closing connection to Endpoint: peer29.org1.example.com:6058, InternalEndpoint: peer29.org1.example.com:6058, PKI-ID: 681f328f15a0aab216ad94f340a1fb06fe315d70a122064955a2191e3442e3c5, Metadata: 
2021-11-30 13:05:25.771 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 06f Exiting
```

core.yaml

```
peer:

    id: jdoe

    networkId: dev

    listenAddress: 0.0.0.0:7051
    address: 0.0.0.0:7051

    addressAutoDetect: false

    # Keepalive settings for peer server and clients
    keepalive:
        interval: 7200s
        timeout: 200s
        minInterval: 60s

        client:
            interval: 60s
            timeout: 200s
        deliveryClient:
            interval: 60s
            timeout: 200s


    # Gossip related configuration
    gossip:
        bootstrap: 127.0.0.1:7051
        useLeaderElection: false
        orgLeader: true

        membershipTrackerInterval: 5s

        endpoint:
        maxBlockCountToStore: 100
        maxPropagationBurstLatency: 10ms
        maxPropagationBurstSize: 100
        propagateIterations: 1
        propagatePeerNum: 3
        pullInterval: 100s
        pullPeerNum: 3
        requestStateInfoInterval: 10s
        publishStateInfoInterval: 10s
        stateInfoRetentionInterval: 1000s
        publishCertPeriod: 100s
        skipBlockVerification: false
        dialTimeout: 10s
        connTimeout: 10s
        recvBuffSize: 200
        sendBuffSize: 200
        digestWaitTime: 1s
        requestWaitTime: 1500ms
        responseWaitTime: 2s
        aliveTimeInterval: 5s
        aliveExpirationTimeout: 25s
        reconnectInterval: 25s
        maxConnectionAttempts: 120
        msgExpirationFactor: 20
        externalEndpoint:

        # Gossip state transfer related configuration
        state:
            enabled: false
            
            checkInterval: 10s
            responseTimeout: 3s
            batchSize: 10
            blockBufferSize: 20
            maxRetries: 3

    tls:
        # Require server-side TLS
        enabled:  false

        clientAuthRequired: false
        # X.509 certificate used for TLS server
        cert:
            file: tls/server.crt
        # Private key used for TLS server
        key:
            file: tls/server.key
        rootcert:
            file: tls/ca.crt
        clientRootCAs:
            files:
              - tls/ca.crt

        clientKey:
            file:
        clientCert:
            file:

    # Authentication contains configuration parameters related to authenticating
    # client messages
    authentication:

        timewindow: 15m

    fileSystemPath: /var/hyperledger/production

    discovery:
        enabled: true
        authCacheEnabled: true
        authCacheMaxSize: 1000
        authCachePurgeRetentionRatio: 0.75
        orgMembersAllowedAccess: false

    # Limits is used to configure some internal resource limits.
    limits:
        concurrency:
            endorserService: 2500
            deliverService: 2500
```

Comment: this is logs of peer23.org1.example.com

Comment: pullInterval is 4s

Comment: gossip requestStateInfoInterval is 10s.

Comment: Forget to say that all my peers and network are bulit on Ubuntu in VMware. All peer  addresses are localhost.

Comment: I test 10 peers network like this. It works well. Maybe localhost can not support 50 peers's gossip communication for too many messages?

Comment: you have 50 peers on the same server? it's too much load